# How to update Anaconda Spyder's Python version

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I'm not trying to update Spyder version, but rather the Python version inside of Spyder.

I've tried `conda update spyder` and `conda update conda`

Comment: Are you running Spyder from conda, right? If that is the case you should be able to change the Python version of the conda environment you are using by running `conda install python=<python version you want>`

Answer (score 1):

You can update Spyder by closing it first, then opening the Anaconda Prompt and running the following commands there

```
conda update anaconda
conda install spyder=5.3.3
```

If you get errors while doing that or it takes too much time, you need to run

```
conda remove spyder
conda install spyder
```

Comment: But that doesn't update the Python version within Spyder, does it?

Comment: Also I'm already on the latest version of spyder (5.4.0), but on Python 3.8